# How do you get the most recent version of Cabal for Haskell?

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've just spent about an hour going in circles trying to get version 2 of Cabal.  Initially I found that the version that came with my LinuxMint install was version 1, so I tried `cabal update`, didn't do it.  So I found instructions which said to use `cabal install Cabal cabal-install`.  Did it, got an error.  Found that the error apparently had to do with using the most current version of Haskell. So I installed version 7 to get Cabal.  Seemed to work, looked like I finally got Cabal version 2.  But I also want the most current version of Haskell so I downloaded the binaries for it and installed that again--now it seems like Cabal is set back to version 1.  Is it not possible to have both version 8 of Haskell and version 2 of Cabal?

Comment: There is a `ppa` that contains the latest GHC versions: https://launchpad.net/~hvr/+archive/ubuntu/ghc

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem When I added it and tried to update, it gave a 404.

Comment: Use [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/).

Comment: @n.m. "Use stack" isn't really an answer to "how do I install cabal-install", especially given that the OP's issue appears to be a pre-installation configuration mixup, as opposed to any difficulties while actually using cabal-install.

Comment: The Cabal homepage https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html has precompiled versions of Cabal-install for various architectures. Regrettably, at this moment there aren't binaries for the latest 2.4 version, only for 2.2. Take care to put the executable in a path that gives it preference to the system-installed one. There are binary packages for GHC as well https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_8_4_4.html#binaries

Comment: Another option is to disregard the GHC/Cabal-install that come with the standard package marager (sometimes they're quite old) and download and install the Haskell Platform instead https://www.haskell.org/platform/

Comment: @danidiaz How do you determine which paths have precedence? The director `~/.cabal/bin` is not in my `PATH` variable, should I put it in toward the front of its definition?

Comment: @danidiaz Also, looking through the Cabal folder, I don't see binaries.  The only folders present are Distribution, Language, tests, and doc.  The `~/.cabal/bin` folder was for the system-installed one but the downloaded one doesn't seem to have a `bin` folder.

Comment: @duplode It's not an answer indeed, because OP is asking a wrong question (XY problem).

Comment: @n.m. What are X and Y, then?

Comment: Cabal is a tool. Tools are out there to help people solve problems. What problem does Cabal help solve? That's X. (Building Haskell programs and libraries).  Any problem with obtaining and using tools would be Y then. A good question is "how do I build Haskell programs and libraries" A good answer is "use stack". It will do the right thing, which includes obtaining and using the correct tools (ghc and cabal) for the package one builds, automatically and transparently.

Comment: @n.m. As far as building Haskell programs and libraries go, cabal-install and Stack are both reasonable options. That being so, it is reasonable to ask about how to get one of them working while expecting an answer involving the tool the question is actually about. I would say that taking "use Stack" as an acceptable answer to any cabal-install question (or vice-versa!) isn't constructive, and claiming the OP has asked a "wrong question" based on such an opinion is rather unpleasant.

Comment: @n.m. Thing is, I don't want to ask how to build programs and libraries.  Mostly I don't want to ask that because I am required to use Cabal by the person who gave me the assignment.

Comment: @duplode I'm trying to be useful, not necessarily pleasant. I believe Stack is useful, more so than global Cabal.

Comment: @n.m. You think being pleasant comes at the cost of being useful?  That sounds like a thin excuse.

Comment: You should mention that you have an assignment in the question, and what is the stated objective. Saves everyone's time. Stack uses Cabal and generates nesessarily Cabal files. If your assignment is to produce a Cabal-based Haskell package, Stack does that. If the assignment is to install Cabal on a computer, then Stack is not an answer.

Comment: @n.m. I'm not sure I need to explain why I'm asking my question ... seems like I should just be able to ask a well-defined question appropriate to StackOverflow.  I shouldn't have to try to anticipate reasons people will spend time trying to not answer the question.

Comment: You don't *need* to explain why you are asking your question or provide extended context. However, doing so tends to help getting more useful answers. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Along the lines of danidiaz's comments, I suggest directly installing cabal-install in your home directory.

Begin by making sure you are actually using the 8.x version of GHC you want (use `which ghc` and `ghc --version` if need be). Also, get rid of any other cabal-install versions you might have installed, so that there is less margin for confusion.

> The [directory] `~/.cabal/bin` is not in my `PATH` variable, should I put it in toward the front of its definition?

Exactly. `~/.cabal/bin` is the default location for executables locally installed with cabal-install, which includes cabal-install itself, and so it must be in the PATH. Putting it towards the front of the PATH will give it priority over any system-wide installation of cabal-install installed with your package managers. (Note that that won't be an issue if you remove said system-wide installation beforehand.)

---

Once the terrain is clear, you can download a suitable binary tarball from [Cabal's download page](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/download.html), extract the executable and put it in `~/.cabal/bin`. As danidiaz notes, the binaries there aren't necessarily at the latest stable version (as I write this, the Linux binaries are 2.2.0.0 rather than 2.4.0.0), but that likely won't matter, as once you have some version of cabal-install available you can simply run...

```sh
cabal new-update # For version 2.4 or above; if not, use cabal update instead.
cabal new-install cabal-install
```

... which will update your cabal-install to the latest stable version.

(Note that I'm using [the new-* cabal-install commands](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build-overview.html). I strongly advise you to do the same.)

---

> Also, looking through the Cabal folder, I don't see binaries. The only folders present are Distribution, Language, tests, and doc.

It sounds like you downloaded the sources of Cabal, the library, rather than the ones of cabal-install, the tool. The cabal-install sources are also available from the download page linked above (as I write this, their version is 2.4.0.0). If you are getting them [from GitHub](https://github.com/haskell/cabal) instead, you should look into the `cabal-install` directory, rather than the `Cabal` one. Either way, once yo are in the appropriate directory, to install from source run...

```sh
./bootstrap.sh --sandbox
```

... which only requires GHC (as opposed to a pre-existing cabal-install). Once it finishes building cabal-install, the script will tell you the location of the executable (presumably in a `.cabal-sandbox/bin` subdirectory). Copy the executable to `~/.cabal/bin` and proceed as before.

Comment: When you say to remove any old installs of Cabal, does that include removing the `~/.cabal/` folder that's currently there from the system-install?

Comment: So what I've done so far is: I did not delete the `~/.cabal` folder as I suspect I shouldn't.  I downloaded the `cabal-install` binaries, moved them to this folder.  Since the folder doesn't have a `bin` folder, should I make one?

Comment: @Addem (1) I suggest that you delete `~/.cabal` as well -- it won't do harm, and it will remove one potential source of confusion. (If you had any executables installed with cabal-install there, you'll have to reinstall them; going by what you say that's not the case, though). (2) Yes, run `mkdir -p ~/.cabal/bin` to create that directory, and put the executable there.

Comment: So I did that, downloaded the Cabal binaries, they were in a .tar.gz, so I moved the tarball to the `.cabal/bin` folder and ran `sudo tar -xvzf ...` and the name of the tarball.  It created a new object called `cabal` but I don't seem to be able to do anything with it.  It's not a folder, or at least, I can't navigate into it.  I tried `./cabal` and `make install` and just `cabal` and `make cabal`.  So I'm really confused about what I should do.  Should I have only moved the file after decompression rather than before?

Comment: @Addem "Should I have only moved the file after decompression rather than before?" -- Indeed. The `cabal` file you extract from the tarball is the executable; you don't need to do anything else with it other than moving it to `~/.cabal/bin`. By the way, don't use `sudo` to extract, or to do anything else: you are working in your home directory, so you don't need elevated permissions to do things.

Comment: Ok, so I deleted everything, decompressed the tarball, made the directories without sudo, moved the binaries in.  Edited my `.bashrc` file so that the PATH is now `/home/addem/.cabal/bin:/home/addem/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH`.  Navigated to `~/.cabal/bin` and entered `cabal new-update`.  I get the error "No cabal.project file or cabal file matching the default glob './*.cabal' was found."  If I enter `cabal new-install cabal-install` it gives the error "Warning: The package list for 'hackage.haskell.org' does not exist. Run 'cabal
update' to download it."

Comment: I tried running the cabal command from several other directories and the behavior was the same.  There's no boostrap file, but I think you mentioned that only if I had the source files, and I've since been trying to work with the binaries.

Comment: @Addem (1) On `new-update`: sorry, I missed that [`new-update` in the 2.2 version doesn't work outside of a project](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5096) -- it does work with 2.4. For this first run, use `cabal update` instead. (2) Now that you have `~/.cabal/bin` in your path, you shouldn't need to navigate to it to run `cabal` -- just open a new terminal or run `source ~/.bashrc` to make sure the new PATH is loaded.

Comment: Finally!  I have Cabal 2 and Haskell 8!  Thanks so much for your help and patience, it was really wonderful to have this assistance.

Comment: @Addem You're welcome; glad it worked out in spite of my slip-ups in the course of explaining it.